# insertOnDuplicate isn't working in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

So I'm trying to check custom database table, if 'something' exists in column 'test_type', replace the existing row with new data. However, it's still continuing writing duplicate column value 'test_type' in the database table. So I end up having two rows of 'something' in 'test_type' column.

```
            $adapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
            $data = array(
                'test_type' => 'something',
                'time_stamp' => $timeStamp,
            );
            $adapter->insertOnDuplicate('test_table', $data, array('test_type'));
```

Here is the update script for creating the table.

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('test_table')};
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('test_table')}` (
  `auto_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `test_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`auto_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Can you post the code for creating the `test_table`? It's possible the unique index hasn't been defined correctly for `insertOnDuplicate` to work

Comment: @Pudge601 script updated thanks

Comment: The only unique index is the auto-incrementing `auto_id` column, which you don't explicitly set the value for. The 'on duplicate' will mean that it updates an existing row if there is a row with the same values for the unique column(s). So, for this example, it would only update a row if you specified `'auto_id' => {a pre-existing id}'`.

Comment: @Pudge601 Ok that wouldn't be my original intention. Is there another way other than insertOnDuplicate to check if a value of a specific column already exists, if so rewrite that row with new data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to make the database understand a duplicate row to mean a row with a `test_type` the same as in an existing row, you could add `test_type` as a column in a unique index, e.g.

```
UNIQUE KEY `test_type_idx` (`test_type`)
```

thus changing your table creation code to be;

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('test_table')};
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('test_table')}` (
  `auto_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `test_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`auto_id`)
  UNIQUE KEY `test_type_idx` (`test_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

");
$installer->endSetup();
```

**EDIT**

The other issue is with the third parameter being passed to the `insertOnDuplicate` method. This should specify the fields which need to be updated if there is a duplicate, so presumably `time_stamp`.

```
$adapter->insertOnDuplicate('test_table', $data, array('time_stamp'));
```

Comment: Ok, the unique key seems to prevent duplicate entry but still doesn't overwrite with new data using insertOnDuplicate?

Comment: Erm.. I think the problem is with the third parameter to the `insertOnDuplicate` method. Just looked up the function, the last parameter should specify which fields should be updated if there is a duplicate. This should presumably be `time_stamp`. Will update answer

Comment: you are correct. time_stamp field should be updated.

Comment: Cool =] so does the solution I put in the edit of my answer solve that?

Comment: haha i didnt even see your updated answer. i took a guess and it worked. thanks man

Comment: Awesome, no problem =]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55024/discussion-between-user2700690-and-pudge601).